# How to complete analysis with small N?

Tags: small-sample, ancova

I have a comparison study of 2 different interventions with students. There are 6 students in 1 class and 10 students in the second class. The statisticians are having a difference of opinion on whether to use ANCOVA because of my small N. T-Test was also taken out as an option. I would appreciate any and all input.

Comment: Have they run tests, observed "non-significant results", and then decided they were unsatisfied with these tests? There is no reason to reject such tests on the basis of a small sample size. Indeed, they're suited to it when assumptions are met.

Comment: from what i understand you have 2 groups of sample sizes 6 and 10? I must say the sample size rather small. Also, your statistical methods is largelt determined by your research question. If you want to compare differences in scores when you want to covary for another variable then yes ANCOVA, t-test is simple straightforward. You spoke about an intervention, do you have pre and post measures of some sort? Nontheless your N is very small, but it depends, have past literature found differences with those sample sizes? Is the sample size right for your research question? Perhaps you may consider

Comment: No, we haven't completed any tests, simply based on low numbers and that "the significance of the statistics is questionable due to the power of the small N."

Comment: I would report the results of the T-test or ANCOVA anyway, commenting that the study may be underpowered.

Comment: @AdamO seems like you could make an answer of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first question is whether the method is appropriate at all to the problem at hand ... Lets say that all the methods under consideration are arguably appropriate, you may then instead want to know which of the methods has most power (rejecting null when its false). You can get a sense of this using simulation. Steps:

1. Use your assumptions about the distribution of scores to generate random data that match the sample sizes you have, based on your null hypothesis being true.
2. Run all the models you're testing against the data. Log the p-values.
3. Repeat N>1000 times.

Power = (no of times null is rejected) / N

Pick the method with the most power.

Answer (score -1):

ANCoVA and t-tests make assumptions about distributions but become resistant against violations of those assumptions with growing $n$. So with small $n$ it is reasonable not rely on these parametric tests but use non-parametric tests instead.

So why not use a simple ranksum test (aka Wilcoxon or Man-Whitney-U) or a permutation test?

Comment: Because these tests have less power than a $t$ test (assuming the data are drawn from a distribution with approximately bell-shaped distribution, and if they data are not, will still have low power at $n_1=6,n_2=10$, even when the non-normality of the distribution is strong)?

Comment: The t test has higher power because it assumes information that we usually do not have. I assume that is exactly the problem that underlies the above question.